# Will changing the product name cause problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, itunes

For the next version of my iPhone app say 1.3 I want to change the product name and i am keeping bundle identifier same as old version. Is it cause any problem in AppStore? that is will be application is treated as update or new version? (I want my application to be treated as update)

FYI: I am changing the product name by editing "Product name" setting in target.

Comment: I just added new name in "bundle display name" key in info.plist for updated version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as long as you keep the bundle ID the same, it's considered to be the same app.

Additionally, in the iTunes Connect portal, you can rename your app when you submit a new version of your app. (I did this with version 2 of Sefira, which I renamed to "[Ultimate Omer 2](http://iTunes.com/apps/Sefira)".)

Just bear in mind that your iTunes "slug" (http://iTunes.com/apps/appname) remains with the first app name.

If you want to change the name of the app as it appears on the device, change the "Bundle Display Name" property in the info plist file.

Comment: Thanks for the details, Moshe - may I ask how you know (and how confident you are) that this is the case? Have you updated an app with a changed Product Name successfully?

Answer (score 2):

No, if you keep your bundle identifier the same, it's considered the same app, whatever you change your app's product name to. The binary with the new product name will be accepted, and devices will download it as an update, as per normal.

Comment: Cheers BoltClock - have you experienced this functionality personally? I'm trying to gauge how confident the answer is =)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "product name" in the configuration will change the executable name also. Since for executable name they used same $PRODUCT_NAME. So it was crashing if i will replace the old version.

The solution i added the key "Bundle display name" in the info.plist and entered to new value for the key.