# If you change your app's name on the App Store do the shortlinks change?

Tags: ios, app-store

We're changing the name of one of our apps on the iTunes App Store.

Say we rename our app from `foo`, to `bar`.

At the moment you can download the app from `http://itunes.com/app/foo`. After the name change will the shortlink also change to `http://itunes.com/app/bar` or is the shortlink tied to the bundle id?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked Apple for details, and this is their reply:

> We understand that you plan to update the name on your app and want to
>   confirm the App's direct URL.
>
> The URL for your application will be www.itunes.com/apps/XXXX where
>   you replace “XXXX” with your app name with no spaces. Once your app
>   has been approved, your direct link should update to reflect your new
>   app name. This link will work within 24 hours of your application
>   going live in the App Store.

**However, at this stage both links work.**
The old link http://www.itunes.com/apps/StoryBot and the new link, http://www.itunes.com/apps/BookBot both work (at this stage). The old one may expire at some point ([try it to see if it has yet](http://www.itunes.com/apps/StoryBot)) but at the time of writing this they both work.

**UPDATE**

After some period of time the original link stopped working, and the new link took affect.

Comment: Did you actually try this? I have seen otherwise where a link to **Game** leads to **Game 2**. I know from experience that Apple support isn't always 100% accurate.

Comment: Not yet no. I'm just working on uploading the binary. A bit nervous because I have to link to the app from inside the app (e.g. share this app with a friend, share on twitter etc.).

Comment: Let us know how it goes. Also try the old link after you change the app name in itunes connect. But be sure to leave the bundle id the same. It atleast used to work where the old appname stayed the same shortlink.

Comment: Hey, do you possibly remember how many days it took until the App Store got rid of the old link and that only the new link worked?

Answer (score 2):

No, the application URL will remain with the first application name.

For example if you have `SuperGame` and submit a version 2 you can then change the application `SuperGame 2` the URL will still be that of `SuperGame`. As long as the bundle ID is the same of course. I have seen an answer on here that mentioned this same thing.

Update:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177561/442695

Comment: Thanks - can anyone confirm this? It's what I suspected by I just want to make sure I don't put any broken links in a shipping app.

Comment: After emailing Apple to check I found that this answer was incorrect - I've added their reply as an answer.