# If you change your apps name in an update, does the App store URL for it change as well?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm going to need to change the name of my app (through no fault of my own) in an update. That's straightforward enough, but what about the Appstore.com/appname URL? does that stay as the original name? or does it update to the new name in the update?

Answer (score 1):

My experience was that the iTunes application URL has changed, but judging by the answer below the old URL should also work for unknown period of time.

Take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812752/1677480

Comment: Thanks ,it looks like it stays the same :(