# How to update app store link. Can i change app store url like Example

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, apple-developer-account

I need to change my app store URL after changing app name for example

app url = https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8&uo=4

and I am trying to change = https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/abcd/id284882215?mt=8&uo=4

I have only need to change only facebook to abcd can I change this plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749141/if-you-change-your-apps-name-on-the-app-store-do-the-shortlinks-change/13812752#13812752 check this link

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a pattern for app link.

`https://apps.apple.com/app/{sku}/id{appId}`

Well, in your case, you changed your app name and you want to update the app link to be with your new app name. But unfortunately, it is the `SKU` that you have to change and it cannot be changed in `appstoreconnect` because it is fixed once you set it on first creating an app on the `appstoreconnect`. Apple designed it to be uneditable.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your app link will be like following way:

`https://apps.apple.com/app/id{{appId}}`

**Reference**: https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201574352-Add-Your-App-s-Apple-App-Store-URL-to-your-Landing-Page