# Change name of app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I created an app id, I then registered that app id at iTunes, I then created the app, and have just been sent an email telling me the app has been approved.

I go to the app store to see if it's available and what do I find? an app with the same name already there! I thought this wasn't possible!!

What can I do? I don't want to delete my app and re-submit the app with a different name all over again (another 10 days of waiting) but I don't see how I can allow my app to be available for sale it there's an app on the app store with the exact same name! (how is this even possible?I thought when it was registered it would stop me from using that name if it was already on the app store??).

I need to change the name, can I do that without resubmitting?

I've been told to change the names (including bundle name) in the plist file in xcode and do an update, but how's that going to be a good thing? as then the bundle name will be different to the one that was registered on ITC, and even if I do do that, don't I have to register a new App ID on the developer portal? (which will then again be different to the one that I first set the app up with on ITC...)

Thanks for all the info so far everyone. I see that I can do an update and change the name, but will that also change the original App store name as well? (www.appstore.com/appname ?)

For anyone that's interested changing the name of your app via an update is a waste of time because the original app store URL stays the same, as described here

[Will changing the product name cause problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119742/will-changing-the-product-name-cause-problem/6177561#6177561)

So completely new build/bundle ID it is then.

Comment: Show me the rule that says two apps can't have the same name.

Comment: Ha, well they got there 3 days before I did, I don't want to get letters from them saying I need to change my name, I might as well do it anyway.

Comment: There are many apps with the same name. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Fogmeister I wouldn't worry about it either, but if their app comes first when you search for it, it's bad.. Users may think it's a bad "copy" and he'll certainly loose downloads.

Comment: you can use `Expedited app review` to improve review process's time, it is under `App Review` in `Contact Us` form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : no, you can't change your app's name without re-submitting. You can change it when you set up an update in iTunes Connect, until your app goes in approval.

As [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08142009a) says :

> Changing the Name of Your App. You can change the name of your
>   existing app only when submitting an update of your app binary. If you
>   submit an app name which is already in use within the same geography
>   in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to enter another name.

Reaction to your edit : no need to change anything in Xcode. All you have to do is set a new name when submitting an update on iTunes Connect. What you can set in Xcode is the name appearing on the springboard. The name appearing in the AppStore is set in iTunes Connect.

In conclusion, setup iTunes Connect for an update, and change the app's name there.

Comment: Just added a new bit to the bottom of my question, regarding what I Was told elsewhere.

Comment: How can I change it in the next release version? I don't see any option to do that in ITC. Also won't putting in an update just take as long for it to get approved as just resubmitting another name completely?

Comment: Resubmitting a new app implies creating a new app ID, renaming stuff, and it's kind of annoying. All you have to do is go to iTunes Connect, select your app, click on "Add version" on the bottom of the page. The popup where you input your update's infos will have an editable "App Name" field. I also believe updates tend to spend less time in review than new apps. But not so sure about that. **But**, what you can do is request an "express update" (I did that once), and your update will be reviewed in about 48 hours. I don't remember exactly the name of this process, but you can look into it.

Comment: As @medvedNick commented on your question, it is called *Expedited app review*

Comment: How do you do a Expedited app review? do you have to email them or something? Also what will be my new App store URL? because I'm using right now www.appstore.com/myapp actually in the game itself, I know I can change the name in the update, but will that effect the actual app store name? and are we sure I don't have to change the bundle name? it's odd to me that the bundle name stays the same, but the ITC name is different.

Comment: For an expedited app review, you need to fill in a form (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite). The ITC name is the name displayed on the AppStore. Your bundle id/name is not at all related to that. Regarding the AppStore URL, I'm not sure how they are built..

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change your apps name without resubmitting. At least not without submitting an update.

**You can change the name of the app every time you release a new update.**

The information can get changed by clicking on "Metadata and Uploads" -> "Edit" on the version details page after creating a new version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the `App Name`  when it is being submitted. The best way is to rename the app in the Next Version Release.

You don't require to do anything with your Xcode Project.

Comment: How can I change it in the next release version? I don't see any option to do that in ITC. Also won't putting in an update just take as long for it to get approved as just resubmitting another name completely?